# Python BeautifulSoup4 Finding Attributes

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Right now i am building a web scraper to grab the actual href link after the  tag to then continue and make a file with all of the values I grab.

I just want to grab the "/groups/1234123" Attribute value and the ID name ("InsertNameHere") but nothing is working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmltext = ''' <div class="sidenav">
         <div class="sidenav-head" id="InsertNameHere">   
          <a href="/groups/1234123/">
           InsertNameHere
          </a>
         </div>
        </div>'''
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find_all('a')
link= s.find('href')

print(link)
```

Im getting the

"AttributeError:ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

I have tried to change the
`link = s.find('href')`
to
`link = s.attrs`

It says I have a different Attribute Error after that.
I also need to keep the `s.find_all()` attribute because there are multiple id's that i need to grab.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>You could try `link= s[0]['href']`</sub>

As the error message indicates, you should have used `s = soup.find('a')` instead of `find_all` which returns a ResultSet (which is like a list of tags). Also, you need to use `.get('href')` or even simply `['href']`, not `.find`; see the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.Tag.attrs) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as

```
s = soup.select_one('a[href]')
print(s['href'])
```